# Remove rotation from a 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix

Tags: math, matrix

I am working on a transformation matrix, and what I want done is to remove the rotation transformation and preserve the scaling, translation, etc.

How do I do this? I am seeking to create a manually-programmed solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an affine matrix decomposition, there are a few methods with different pros and cons. You'll have to look into it. Here are a few links to get you started though:

http://callumhay.blogspot.com/2010/10/decomposing-affine-transforms.html

http://www.itk.org/pipermail/insight-users/2006-August/019025.html

This could be simpler or more complicated depending on the nature of your transformation though, I'm assuming it's affine. But if it's linear / rigid then this is much easier, if it's a perspective transformation then I imagine it will be more complex.

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure that your matrix is rotation+translation+scaling then you can just extract the parameters you need:

```
rotation = atan2(m12, m11)
scale = sqrt(m11*m11 + m12*m12)
translation = (m31, m32)
```

## edit

I didn't notice that you are interested in 3d transformations, in that case the rotation part is the annoying one, but if you just want translation and scale...

```
translation = (m41, m42, m43)
scale = sqrt(m11*m11 + m12*m12 + m13*m13)
```

Comment: Well if there is only translation, scaling and rotation - then one could remove the rotation by extracting the translation and scaling components and multiplying them together and just ignore what was left over...

Comment: Also is your scaling assuming uniform scaling in each direction? This might not be the case, i.e. image could be stretched

Comment: @Dan: with "annoying" I mean simply that representing "the essence" of rotation with free coordinates as nicely as it's done in 2D is impossible (see gimbal lock problem). About scaling note that if you allow non-uniform scaling and rotation the closure becomes much more general and the very concept of what are the rotation angles becomes questionable even far from the singularity scale=0.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the matrix is not restricted to uniform scaling,and it is 3D.

Answer (score 2):

The 4×4 homogeneous transformation matrix is defined by:

```
| x2 |   | R11*SX R12*SY R13*SZ TX | | x1 |
| y2 | = | R21*SX R22*SY R23*SZ TY | | y1 |
| z2 |   | R31*SX R32*SY R33*SZ TZ | | z1 |
| 1  |   | 0      0      0      1  | |  1 |
```

where `(SX,SY,SZ)` are scaling factors, `(TX,TY,TZ)` are translation factors and `Rij` are rotation coefficients.

To get the translation is trivial since you pick the last column. To get the scaling you use the property that the transformation is a rotation times a diagonal scaling (`A=R*S`) and thus

```
tr(A)*A = tr(R*S)*(R*S) = tr(S)*tr(R)*R*S = tr(S)*S
```

where `tr(A)` is the transpose operator. To get the scaling factors compute

```
S2 = tr(A)*A
```

and pick the square root of first three diagonal terms

```
SX = sqrt(S2(1,1))
SY = sqrt(S2(2,2))
SZ = sqrt(S2(3,3))
```

Then assemble the new transformation as:

```
| SX   0   0  TX |
|  0  SY   0  TY |
|  0   0  SZ  TZ |
|  0   0   0   1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of the solutions so far. A 3x4 (or 4x4) affine transform first applies a rotation, then translation in the target frame. The final column vector in that transform is the translation, but in the target frame, not the original frame! So if we inverse the transform, then we can take the final column vector as the translation in the original frame instead.

Here is how I did it (in numpy):

```
b_to_a = np.linalg.inv(a_to_b)
a_to_b_only_translation = np.eye(4)
a_to_b_only_translation[:,3] = -b_to_a[:,3]
```